# Assign variable set in one function to a variable in another function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign the variable `strSel` in the function `outputSelected` to the variable `TestVar` in the function `testResults`. What's the best way to achieve this?

```
function getSelected(opt) {
    var selected = new Array();
    var index = 0;
    for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < opt.length; intLoop++) {
        if ((opt[intLoop].selected) || (opt[intLoop].checked)) {
            index = selected.length;
            selected[index] = new Object;
            selected[index].value = opt[intLoop].value;
            selected[index].index = intLoop;
        }
    }

    return selected;
}

function outputSelected(opt) {
    var sel = getSelected(opt);
    var strSel = "";
    for (var item in sel)       
    strSel += sel[item].value + ",";
    window.document.title = strSel;
}

function testResults (form) {
    var TestVar = // Want to pass strSel here.
window.document.title=(TestVar);
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make much sense as asked.  When are any of the functions called? What value are you trying to get from where, into what?  Try making a much simpler example of what you are trying to do, rather than just copy/pasting your actual code - most of which is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Just use a global variable :-

then set this variable in one function and you can use this variable value in another function.

```
var myvar;// declare global variable
 function outputSelected(opt) {
        var sel = getSelected(opt);
        var strSel = "";
        for (var item in sel)       
           strSel += sel[item].value + ",";
        // set the var:-
         myvar=strSel ;
         window.document.title=(strSel);  <----- result      

     }
     function testResults (form) {

        var TestVar= myvar;
        //alert (TestVar + "\n" + TestVar1 + "\n" + TestVar2 + "\n" + TestVar3 + "\n" + TestVar4 + "\n" + TestVar5);
        window.document.title=(TestVar);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable or return the value in the function `outputSelected()` and call and assign it in your other function.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the value from `outputSelected` and then pass it into your `testResults` method:

Changes:

```
function outputSelected(opt) {
    // current code
    return strSel;
}

function testResults(form) {
    var TestVar = form;

    window.document.title = TestVar;
}
```

And call the methods like so:

```
testResults(outputSelected(opt));
```